# App.config not accessible when built in Settings

Tags: c#, app-config, application-settings, configurationmanager, appsettings

I have a very simple app that I am trying to build an app.config using the Settings property. The app.config is built, but when run, the keys are not retrieving values.

I had originally used the adding of an Application Configuration File from the project and hand building the app.config with great success The hand-built app.config is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Hosppath" value="C:\events\inbound"/>
    <add key="Vendpath" value="C:\events\outbound"/>
    <add key="Hospname" value="OBLEN_COB_Active_Inv_Advi_Daily_.csv"/>
    <add key="Vendname" value="Advi_OBlen_Active_Inv_Ack_Daily_.csv"/>
    <add key="Hospkey" value="invoice_number"/>
    <add key="Vendkey" value="invoice"/>
    <add key="Outpath" value="C:\events\Reports"/>
    <add key="Outname" value="OB_Exception_Report_.xlsx"/>
    <add key="Hospexcpt" value="O'Bleness Exceptions"/>
    <add key="Vendexcpt" value="AdviCare Exceptions"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

The calling class is here:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;

namespace LoadSettings
{
    public static class ConfigReader
    {
        public static bool ReadAllSettings()
        {
            var success = false;
            var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

            if(appSettings.Count > 0)
            {
                success = true;
            }
            return success;
        }

        public static string ReadSetting(string key)
        {
            string result = "";

            var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
            result = appSettings[key] ?? "Not Found";

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

The Main() function looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;

namespace LoadSettings
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string hospPath;
            string vendPath;
            string hospName;
            string vendName;
            string hospKey;
            string vendKey;
            string rptPath;
            string rptName;
            string sht1Name;
            string sht2Name;

            if (ConfigReader.ReadAllSettings())
            {
                hospPath = ConfigReader.ReadSetting("Hosppath");
                vendPath = ConfigReader.ReadSetting("Vendpath");
                hospName = ConfigReader.ReadSetting("Hospname");
                vendName = ConfigReader.ReadSetting("Vendname");
                hospKey = ConfigReader.ReadSetting("Hospkey");
                vendKey = ConfigReader.ReadSetting("Vendkey");
                rptPath = ConfigReader.ReadSetting("Outpath");
                rptName = ConfigReader.ReadSetting("Outname");
                sht1Name = ConfigReader.ReadSetting("Hospexcpt");
                sht2Name = ConfigReader.ReadSetting("Vendexcpt");

                Console.WriteLine("The hospital file path is:      {0}", hospPath);
                Console.WriteLine("The vendor file path is:        {0}", vendPath);
                Console.WriteLine("The hospital file name is:      {0}", hospName);
                Console.WriteLine("The vendor file name is:        {0}", vendName);
                Console.WriteLine("The hospital key field is:      {0}", hospKey);
                Console.WriteLine("The vendor key field is:        {0}", vendKey);
                Console.WriteLine("The exceptions report path is:  {0}", rptPath);
                Console.WriteLine("The exceptions report name is:  {0}", rptName);
                Console.WriteLine("The sheet1 tab name is:         {0}", sht1Name);
                Console.WriteLine("The sheet2 tab name is:         {0}", sht2Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works like a champ, but as soon as I try to build it in the Settings, I get nothing back. Here is Settings:

[image: Settings image]

The created app.config looks perfectly normal:

[image: Renamed to proper application_name.exe.config name]

Inside, the contents match the keys and values placed in Settings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="OHS_RCIS.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
        <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="OHS_RCIS.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <userSettings>
        <OHS_RCIS.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="Hospkey" serializeAs="String">
                <value>invoice_number</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Vendkey" serializeAs="String">
                <value>invoice</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Column2" serializeAs="String">
                <value>curr_tot_acct_bal</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Column3" serializeAs="String">
                <value>COL_AGNCY_NAME</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Column4" serializeAs="String">
                <value>admit_date</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Column5" serializeAs="String">
                <value>discharge_date</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Column6" serializeAs="String">
                <value>create_date</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Column7" serializeAs="String">
                <value>HSP_ACCOUNT_ID</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Outpath" serializeAs="String">
                <value>C:\events\Reports</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Outname" serializeAs="String">
                <value>COB_OB_Advi_Placement_Exceptions_.xlsx</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Hospexcpt" serializeAs="String">
                <value>O\'Bleness Exceptions</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Vendexcpt" serializeAs="String">
                <value>AdviCare Exceptions</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Tab1Color" serializeAs="String">
                <value>FFFFE1FF</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Tab2Color" serializeAs="String">
                <value>FFE4E1FF</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="ColumnCount" serializeAs="String">
                <value>7</value>
            </setting>
        </OHS_RCIS.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
    <applicationSettings>
        <OHS_RCIS.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="Hosppath" serializeAs="String">
                <value>C:\events\inbound</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Vendpath" serializeAs="String">
                <value>C:\events\outbound</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Hospname" serializeAs="String">
                <value>O\'Bleness Exceptions</value>
            </setting>
            <setting name="Vendname" serializeAs="String">
                <value>AdviCare Exceptions</value>
            </setting>
        </OHS_RCIS.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

The code used to access the app.config looks like this with some added lines trying to coax results:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;

namespace OHS_RCIS.Utility
{
    public static class ConfigReader
    {
        public static bool ReadAllSettings()
        {
            var success = false;
            ConfigurationManager.GetSection("userSettings");
            ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("userSettings");
            var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;

            if (appSettings.Count > 0)
            {
                success = true;
            }
            return success;
        }

        public static string ReadSetting(string key)
        {
            string result = "";

            var appSettings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
            result = appSettings[key] ?? "Not Found";

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: The calls where it fails in Main()]

I am obviously missing something when doing it through Settings, but have the proper references,

[image: References]

can see the app.config is properly built, and am using the same general code as in my test snippet.

[image: Seen through Debugger]

Any clues?

Answer (score 6):

You're using it wrong! Please stop doing what you're doing (unless I completely misunderstand your requirement...)!!

When using the builtin settings mechanism, Visual Studio creates and maintains the `app.config` file and a `Settings` class for you already. The `app.config` file will be renamed and copied to the output directory as `applicationname.exe.config` when you build your solution.

All you need to do is access your settings through the auto-generated properties. This works for application and user settings alike. In your example:

```
string s = Properties.Settings.Default.Hospkey;
```

**Done! Nothing more!**

If you want to change user settings, do something like this:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.UserSettingName = value;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

**Done! Nothing more!**

Please stop using the configuration manager or anything, also don't include the `app.config` file in your output. It's all there by default!

User settings are for values that the user should be able to change **through your application's GUI** (for example a settings dialog) or will change depending on the application's state (such as persisting window locations, MRU files, etc.) and will be saved within the user profile somewhere (it doesn't matter where that is - just take it as a given) and also be read from there automatically.

When you update your application, you may end up with default values from your build. In that case, please follow the [instructions here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38103647/117362). **You can not overwrite user settings by changing the .exe.config file in your installation folder, as they will only be read from there upon the first run!**

Application settings are for default values the user should not be able to change. You can change these manually in the .exe.config file if necessary.

Comment: Thank you Thorsten! A coworker had "helped" me by showing me how to create an app.config file using Settings. I put it back to using an added Application Configuration File and things are good. I had already discovered the "Properties.Settings.Default" syntax, but it doesn't allow what I needed. This needs to be a flexible file to be created for the same code being used for similar reports, and permanent Settings defeats that purpose.

Comment: I up-arrowed your answer, but do not have the reputation for it to appear.

Comment: The question is then whether on that case you should use something else to store the settings - maybe some custom XML format?